# Check for the existence of a value in a WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I want to retrieve data from WPF datagrid depending on certain condition. But the problem is, I am not sure if the data exist. How to check it?

Comment: What data are you hoping to retrieve? How is the data bound to your grid? It is difficult to answer your question with any certainty without a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you've some Collection or List bound to the datagrid. If so you can query it like this:

```
var query = yourList.Where(item => item.Name = "abc" ); // retrieve items having Name 'abc'

var retrievedItems;
if(query.Any)
{
    retrievedItems = query.ToList();
}
```